# IOS XCode Tuxedo button shows wrong class

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

- My app has multiple storyboards and multiple view controllers
- My SignIn Storyboard has a custom 'SignInVC' view controller class
- This is set in the interface builder
- I press the tuxedo button and it opens up split screen
- It always opens the *wrong* view controller file (MasterVC).
- I can manually open the correct VC file, but, when I click on a control (to begin the binding) It will go ahead and open MasterVC for me (gee thanks!)
- This makes binding my view to my controller using the interface impossible
- How can resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Above interface builder is a breadcrumb like control with a listing of documents. Press the Manual button and select the correct view controller.